# How to get the Time from Firebase Realtime Database in my android chat app

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an simple chat app with Temporary chatRooms

I'm using an single Text view to show username and chat message with below code

```
private void append_chat_conversation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

    while (i.hasNext()){

           chat_msg = (String) ((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();
        chat_user_name = (String) ((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();

        chat_conversation.append(chat_user_name +" : "+chat_msg +" \n");
    }
```

and layout for the chat activity is

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_send"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btn_send"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btn_send">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
</ScrollView>
```

Now also I would like to show the Date and Time on which message received. How can I do this. For example, I will like to get the time as below in my app

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vp4Q.jpg)

My Firebase cloud structure is

[Firebase Cloud Storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGsKO.jpg)

you can find the whole project here

https://github.com/miskoajkula/Firebase-RealtimeDatabase-App-Example

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can send time or any other things you need along with your message in json format and parse when receive.

Comment: @Khemraj How can I do that can you show me with some example??

Comment: Okay i will post one for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use FirebaseListAdapter for ease of use. like

```
ListView listOfMessages = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_of_messages);

adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(this, ChatMessage.class,
        R.layout.message, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()) {
    @Override
    protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
        // Get references to the views of message.xml
        TextView messageText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
        TextView messageUser = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
        TextView messageTime = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

        // Set their text
        messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
        messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());

        // Format the date before showing it
        messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",
                model.getMessageTime()));
    }
};

listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I also implemented chat like this. [Reference](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-an-android-chat-app-using-firebase--cms-27397)

If you use recycler view then use [link](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-firebaseui-with-custom-firebaserecycleradapter-example-tutorial/)

Comment: yes I also searched and found the same Refrence, But I also needed the Parent chat Rooms and inside parent chat room  i wanted to implement chat activity..but the refrece has only one chat room..so I found this one....Ok I'll try and hope it works.

Comment: You have list view or recycler view